# Edição de Controle de Acesso ASP.NET MVC Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Bom Dia!

Tenho um projeto criado e nele já contém um sistema de controle de acesso que foi criado automaticamente quando criei o projeto, gostaria de saber se seria possível editar este controle de acesso ou se seria melhor criar um novo, gostaria de enviar os dados para uma tabela em meu banco, atualmente ele esta se utilizando esta conexão:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Administracao-20151103112933.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Administracao-20151103112933;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

O que devo fazer para salvar estes registros no meu BD? (abaixo a minha conexão com meu BD)

```
    <add name="naescola" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=NaEscola;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Min Pool Size=50" />
```

Comment: Explique melhor o que é seu controle de acesso: ASP.NET Identity, Membership ou ele é alguma coisa mais customizada?

Answer (score 1):

Basta você mudar a `DefaultConnection` para apontar para seu banco, ele vai criar as tabelas todas (todas do zero).

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=IP;Initial Catalog=NOBD;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=USUARIO;Password=SENHA;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Essa minha é uma que eu fiz exatamente isso que você quer, para *SQLServer*

Comment: Mas como posso saber quais tabelas e campos a `DefaultConnection` precisa? Tenho uma tabela ´Login{ idLogin, Usuario, senha, privilegio, email }´,  ele irá identificar automaticamente?

Comment: Ele vai criar tudo para vc, como faz no localdb.

Comment: teria que ficar deste jeito a minha connection?
`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=NaEscola;Persist Security Info=True;User Id=USUARIO;Password=SENHA;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: Não, vc está apontando para (localdb), pega a minha da resposta e troca o IP, NOBD, USUARIO e SENHA se for sqlserver

Comment: É SQL Server, porem como o meu banco é de teste esta no meu localhost, não existe usuario e senha, colocquei (localdb) pq na minha outra connection esta (localdb) tambem 
`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=NaEscola;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` deste modo estaria correto?

Comment: Tem que testar.. cria uma conexão no conection explores, lá tem um visual para criar, aí pega a string de conexão gerada nele e usa, vai funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa criar uma ligação entre o seu projeto e banco de dados, o **Entity Framework** é o responsável por isso, pra quem está começando o **Wizard** ajuda bastante.

Na Model do seu projeto, ao clicar com o botão direito, escolha a Opção *Add* à *New Item*. Na tela que irá aparecer escolha a opção **Data** no navegador, que está na lateral esquerda, e no quadrado à direita escolha a opção **ADO.NET Entity Data Model**. No exemplo abaixo o nome do projeto é ControleAcesso.cs.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode acompanhar o restante do passo a passo [AQUI](http://www.devmedia.com.br/website-com-controle-de-acesso-usando-asp-net-mvc-bootstrap-e-razor/33093).

Referências: Devmidia.